# Virtualbox install error

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm trying to install virtualbox on a ubuntu14.04 server. During the installation I get an error that states:

> no path found matching pattern
>   /lib/modules/3.10.61-ltsi-06292015/kernel vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at
>   /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong.

Inside the log:

> Makefile:187: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current
>   Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR= and run Make again.  Stop.

It also suggests that I run: apt-get install -headers-3.10.61-ltsi-06292015, but that doesn't seem to be valid syntax. I've looked around and tried installing linux-headers-$(uname -r) and linux-headers-generic, but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you upgrade Ubuntu before you installed Virtualbox?

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

or at least do an update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in CENTOS. Here is how I solved it. Hope it helps:

Problem:
"Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR= and run Make again. Stop."

Solution: 
Use the following - `export KERN_DIR=/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.4.5.el7.x86_64`(in my case)
In your case, it will be export KERN_DIR=/usr/src/kernels/*number*

Please go to /usr/src/kernels and check for the *number*.

If nothing exists, please do  `yum install kernel-devel`, or equivalent of apt-get install kernel-devel. Check error in the log you mentioned above again.

Please note: The above command gets closest kernel-devel. It should exactly match the value in the error. Find the rpm and install.

In case of CENTOS, I used the following:

```
wget http://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/cern/centos/7/updates/x86_64/Packages/kernel-devel-3.10.0-327.4.5.el7.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh kernel-devel-3.10.0-327.4.5.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

And then, set `export KERN_DIR=/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.4.5.el7.x86_64` to a proper value

All the best.